# CAAnimation to end before it reaches it's destination

Tags: ios, calayer, uibezierpath, caanimation

I have a `CaLayer` that is moving with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. I want to end the movement of the Layer before it reaches the end, because a random number of Layers are moving towards a single destination from different locations, and when they reach it, it looks like a snowflake.

```
CGPoint startPoints = [self convertDegreesToPoints:latLonArr];
CGPoint endPoints = [self convertDegreesToPoints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"41.0311",@"21.3403", nil]];

UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[linePath moveToPoint:startPoints];
[linePath addLineToPoint:endPoints];

//gradient layer for the line


CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150.0, 2.0);
gradient.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],(id)[[colors objectAtIndex:i] CGColor],(id)[[colors objectAtIndex:i] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];
[scrollViewContent.layer addSublayer:gradient];



CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = [linePath CGPath];
anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
anim.repeatCount = 0;
anim.duration = 1;
[gradient addAnimation:anim forKey:@"gradient"];
```

and here is how it looks:

[image]

This question is referral to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125910/cagradientlayer-to-blend-in-with-the-end-location-of-the-cakeyframeanimation

I decided to ask again because maybe I was not clear enough in the previous one, or title was to strange for someone who knows how, to look into it.

Comment: Couldn't you have edited and made the original question more clear instead of asking a new question?

Comment: I've voted it for closing, and thanks for your answer on this :S